Expo project add comments to build
I am working with building multiple apps with React Native and Expo.
I was wondering it there was a way to add comments when you make a build. For example, I would love to be able to see in Expo that Build 21 was for xyz features.

EAS Metadata has a releaseNotes property but it is for iOS only for now.
https://docs.expo.dev/eas/metadata/schema/

Thank you so much!! This is what I have been looking for
